# Scrolling DIV on static body scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a static body element and a DIV inside it, which height is 500px. It has overflow: visible and text longer than 500px. I want to scroll that DIV while I have mouse pointer over body (which doesn't have any scrollbars itself).

Any directions?

[Pic related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO9pI.jpg) - the mouse pointer is outside of the DIV I want to scroll

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: Setting the DIV to position: fixed and its top, bottom, left and right to 0, but it resizes elements inside of it

Comment: so basically you want to scroll it when the mouse pointer is not inside it?

Comment: I hate it when guys here bully new people by downvoting and deleting their questions instead of correcting them and helping them :/

Comment: Try triggering scroll event on inner div (which you want to scroll) when scroll event occurs on body element

Answer (score 0):

You may try it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($('selector:hover').length != 0) {
    $(document).scrollTo('selector');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. For anyone who finds this thread:

```
/** This is high-level function.
* It must react to delta being more/less than zero.
*/
function handle(delta) {
var target = $('#scrollable_content');
var top = target.scrollTop() - delta;
target.scrollTop(top);
}

/** Event handler for mouse wheel event.
*/
function wheel(event){
var delta = 0;
if (!event) /* For IE. */
        event = window.event;
if (event.wheelDelta) { /* IE/Opera. */
        delta = event.wheelDelta/120;
} else if (event.detail) { /** Mozilla case. */
        /** In Mozilla, sign of delta is different than in IE.
         * Also, delta is multiple of 3.
         */
        delta = -event.detail/3;
}

/** If delta is nonzero, handle it.
 * Basically, delta is now positive if wheel was scrolled up,
 * and negative, if wheel was scrolled down.
 */
if (delta) handle(delta);

/** Prevent default actions caused by mouse wheel.
 * That might be ugly, but we handle scrolls somehow
 * anyway, so don't bother here..
 */
if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
event.returnValue = false;
}


if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', 
wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
```